# Pareto Chart - when can be used?

Tags: data-visualization, barplot, pie-chart

I have a question on the Pareto Chart.

I know it has been originally used in quality control, but do you think it is good to apply it to other domains as well?

I have recently built a Pareto Chart to display the potential pipeline of a business by its target markets.

I chose the Pareto because it was clear that the first two markets would potentially account for almost 80% of total potential sales, while the other 4 would not be very significant.

A colleague of mine told me that the Pareto chart is not a good choice to display these kinds of information and that is rarely used anyway. He suggested that a separate bar graph and a pie chart alongside it would convey a better message.

My question is if it was good to use the Pareto Chart in this case. I think it is a very powerful way to display what was behind those numbers compared to a two separate charts.